# How to change the text color of only the cell that is clicked on a GridView in QML?

Tags: qt, gridview, qml

In a GridView, I want to change the color of the text that is on the cell that is clicked.

The code below changes the color of the text contained in all the cells, not only the one that was clicked.

What needs to be done to change only the text of the cell that is clicked?

```
property string textColor: "black";

GridView {
        id: gridAmplitudeValues
        x: 20; y: 63;
        width: 544; height: 227;
        cellWidth: 136; cellHeight: 38
        interactive: false
        
        Component {
            id: cellContent

            Rectangle {
                width: 117; height: 38;
                color: "lightgreen";
                Text {
                    id: textValue;
                    text: "text";
                    color: textColor;
                }
                
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked:{
                        gridAmplitudeValues.currentIndex = model.index;
                        textColor = "red";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        model: 24
        delegate: cellContent
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `textColor` property is defined outside the grid. So when you change it, it affects all the cells. You can fix this by using some other state property, and changing the color of the text based on that state.

```
property string textColor: "black";

GridView {
    Component {
        id: cellContent

        // Store the clicked state in a property
        property bool cellClicked: false

        Rectangle {
            Text {
                // Make the text color dependent on the clicked state
                color: cellClicked ? "red" : textColor
            }
                
            MouseArea {
                onClicked:{
                    // Update the clicked state
                    cellClicked = !cellClicked;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    model: 24
    delegate: cellContent
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To make it so only one item is red at a time, you can make use of the GridView's currentIndex property.

```
GridView {
    id: gridAmplitudeValues

    Component {
        id: cellContent

        Rectangle {
            Text {
                // Make the text color dependent on the currentIndex
                color: gridAmplitudeValues.currentIndex === index ? "red" : textColor
            }

            MouseArea {
                onClicked:{
                    // Update the currentIndex
                    gridAmplitudeValues.currentIndex = index;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    model: 24
    delegate: cellContent
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this worked partially (after puting the cellClicked inside Rectangle otherwise there was an error). Now, the text changes to RED when clicked but when another cell is clicked the previously clicked ones remain RED, I am looking for a solution to have only current clicked one RED. I am thinking there needs to be somehow a use of the model.index and/or currentIndex but not sure how exactly...

Comment: That requirement was never listed in your question. I will update my answer.

Comment: And yes, you were right about my typo with cellClicked. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! works perfectly and sorry for forgetting to mention that last requirement.